# Visual Studio Code: How to Disable Drag to Edit Text?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VS Code how can I disable Drag to Edit Text?

When editing in Visual Studio Code, often when I attempt to select an area of text, I accidentally select a few characters. When I drag, the characters are moved. Seems I'm inept at using a mouse.

How can I disable drag to edit? I searched online and in keyboard shortcuts. No luck.

Comment: Text Drag and Drop has another issue: it prevents you from renewing selection by clicking inside a highlighted area of text (whether to place the cursor in the middle or select another area inside). Disabling Drag and Drop with the answers below allows clicking inside again!

Answer (score 69, accepted):

> // Controls if the editor should allow to move selections via drag and drop.
>
> "editor.dragAndDrop": false,

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks very much!

Comment: Thanks this helped

Comment: This should be the default setting anyway, drag & drop text is an unusability evil!    So many times I've accidentally moved text when just trying to select, then have to undo and start again.

Answer (score 12):

In Visual Studio Code if you want to do in the app just go to:

File -> Preferences -> Settings -> type "Drag and drop" in the search bar

It should be the first option.

Answer (score 8):

Just to complete the answer : 
in Visual Studio : 
Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> General -> Drag and Drop text editing
( or directly enter "Drag and Drop" in the search bar of the Options window )